# Improve minor edit without wait to accept is this good?

Tags: discussion

I am targeting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30100313/javascript-not-entered) question. Here the question owner ask one question with lots of only description. But they didn't post code in question. Then after they post code in comment.

Many people ask to put code in question using edit question but upto that there are many downvote and closevote on that question. 
After that  one person Edit question who has less than 2000 rep. one person approve that. Now i see there that down vote is continuously increasing.

**My question:** 
I decide to improve some small edit like, just comma instead of approve and wait for another 3rd person to get approve. Because upto that down vote is continuously increase and question may be closed.

So, it is better to improved edit(just minor) or Approve and wait for another approve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the code itself does little to clarify what the OP is actually asking about, so I don't think there's any need to do that. (There was already two approve votes by the time you chose to "Improve Edit" anyway, so it wouldn't have made much of a difference.)

I think it'd be better to comment specifically asking for the code that's actually *relevant* to answering the OP's question.

In general though, I would recommend not doing this unless you are very sure that the edit is sufficiently beneficial as this can be seen as circumventing the review process and places the responsibility on you to ensure that the post is in a good state as you have edited it yourself.